# htaccess rewrite rule for multiple get

Tags: .htaccess

if one get parameter , i can write right. but when the multiple parameter for get i couldnt make rewrite rule

```
RewriteRule "^etkinlik-detay/(.*)/(.*)$" "$etkinlik-detay.php?club_sef_link=$1&sef_link=$2 [L]
```

i get an page not found error. how can i fix this problem ?
here is all my htaccess:

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule "^bar/(.*)$" "bar.php?sef_link=$1"
RewriteRule "^etkinlik-detay/(.*)/(.*)$" "$etkinlik-detay.php?club_sef_link=$1&sef_link=$2 [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the "leading $" from  your Second rule target,

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule "^bar/(.*)$" "bar.php?sef_link=$1"
RewriteRule ^etkinlik-detay/(.*)/(.*)$ etkinlik-detay.php?club_sef_link=$1&sef_link=$2 [L,NC]
```